# MYSQL FULLTEXT search for multi kewords

Tags: mysql, match, against

I have field called `keywords` and the stored info is a keywords separated with `|`

For example:

```
sky|Banana is good|apple|apple is red|sky is blue|green
```

What i'm try to do is search in that field and find results that contains at least one of the keywords.

For that i used MATCH AGAINST in BOOLEAN MODE

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE MATCH(kewords) 
      AGAINST ('+sky is blue +Banana is good +otherword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But results is goes wrong, for example it will select results that contains `+sky is blue` and also with a single word `sky`

I know how to solve that in PHP, but i'm looking for MYSQL solution, i thought Match AGAINST is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `LIKE`, fencing the search words with the delimiter:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE CONCAT('|', keywords, '|') LIKE '%|sky is blue|%' OR
      CONCAT('|', keywords, '|')LIKE '%|Banana is good|%' OR
      CONCAT('|', keywords, '|') LIKE '%|otherword|%'
```

This ensures that the search phrase must match exactly (i.e. `sky is blue` will not match `sky`).

If you want all the phrases to be present (instead of any), just change the `OR` to `AND`.

Comment: +1 it seems that LIKE is the only way to do that, but it's not the solution in my situation since i have a lot of keywords, i'm going to take care of that by using PHP, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2203703 Thanks. PHP is probably the way to go. The MySQL match function isn't really well designed for the way your table is set up.